# Unit testing ArrayMap throws Method put in android.util.ArrayMap not mocked

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a method that uses array map and I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in android.util.ArrayMap not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

code:

```
  ArrayMap<String, String> sampleMap =new ArrayMap<>();
                            for (SampleInfo info : details.getSampleList())
                            {
                                sampleMap.put(info.getkey(),info.getName());
                            }
```

I have tried:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

This way the exception is avoided but the map is always empty. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me, make sure its in the correct part of the build.gradle

```
android {

  ...

  testOptions { 
     unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

Comment: this makes it not give an error, but it does not return the value if you try to do a get(nullPointerException)

Comment: @ShadowFlame take a look at the documentation, maybe this will help you https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: i should probably update this question. I have found a solution by depending on a support library, instead of the device-library

Answer (score 1):

As @ShadowFlame  stated on above comment 
I used  array map support "androidx.collection.ArrayMap" instead of "android.util.ArrayMap"
and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try because it is ArrayMap using key value/pair

```
        ArrayList<ArrayMap<String, String>> listArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SampleInfo info1 : details.getSampleList())
        {
            sampleMap.put("keyname",info1.getName());

            listArray2.add(sampleMap);

        }
        Log.e("****sadflkj **",listArray2.toString());
```