# Method put in android.util.SparseArray not mocked

Tags: android-studio, junit4

I would like to run a test which contains this code:

```
    @Test
    public void deleteItemWithKeyGreaterThenTest() {
        SparseArray<String> sparseArray = new SparseArray<String>();
        sparseArray.put(0, "zero");
```

but when I run the test I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in android.util.SparseArray not mocked.
```

I've already read this [Unit testing ArrayMap throws Method put in android.util.ArrayMap not mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124522/unit-testing-arraymap-throws-method-put-in-android-util-arraymap-not-mocked) but it did not provide a clear solution.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: full code

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import android.util.SparseArray;

@Test
public void deleteItemWithKeyGreaterThenTest() {
    SparseArray<String> sparseArray = new SparseArray<String>();
    sparseArray.put(0, "zero");
    assertEquals(sparseArray.size(), 1);
}
```

also tried both:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navmaze"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

and

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navmaze"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

and these are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, android development is a mess.  Does clearing your maven repo help as suggested here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4740?

Comment: I don't have any maven repo to clean...

Comment: Well then!  I suppose that's not it.  =/

Comment: Can you post your dependencies section / mocking configuration?

Comment: I added some information.

Comment: Ok, if you don't actually have a `dependencies` section that brings in junit and something that has or can provide a SparseArray mock, you will need to put one in.  See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the dependencies section... ^^ added to the question now.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this documentation [unitTest](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#mocking-dependencies), it seems that in tests the package Android is just something like an "empty" implementation.